# Gantt chart started compiling in a wrong way recently

Tags: pgfgantt

I have the following Gantt chart (generated by pgfgantt package) in one of my documents:

```
\begin{ganttchart}[
    inline, 
    hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
    vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
    title top shift = .4,
    group label font = \tiny,
    group left shift = .1,
    group right shift = -.1,
    bar label font = \tiny,
    milestone label font = \tiny,
    bar label inline anchor/.style={above=0.1cm},
    milestone label inline anchor/.style={above=0.1cm}
  ]{24}{24}
  \gantttitle{Month}{24}\\
  \gantttitlelist{1,...,24}{1}\\
  \ganttbar[inline=false,bar/.style={draw=none, fill=none},bar label font = \normalfont]{Work packages}{1}{1}
  \ganttgroup{Familiarising}{1}{6}
  \ganttgroup{Core}{6}{12}
  \ganttgroup{Application}{13}{24}\\
  %DELIVERABLES
  \ganttbar[inline=false,bar/.style={draw=none, fill=none},bar label font = \normalfont]{Deliverables}{1}{1}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=blue}]{1.1}{3}{3}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=blue}]{1.2}{6}{6}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=blue}]{2.1,2.2,2.3}{12}{12}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=blue}]{3.2,3.4}{18}{18}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=blue}]{3.1,3.3}{24}{24}\\
  %MILESTONES
  \ganttbar[inline=false,bar/.style={draw=none, fill=none},bar label font = \normalfont]{Milestones}{1}{1}
  \ganttmilestone{6m}{6}
  \ganttmilestone{12m}{12}
  \ganttmilestone{18m}{18}
  \ganttmilestone{24m}{24}\\
  %SEMINARS
  \ganttbar[inline=false,bar/.style={draw=none, fill=none},bar label font = \normalfont]{Seminars}{1}{1}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=orange}]{}{3}{3}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=orange}]{}{9}{9}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=orange}]{}{15}{15}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=orange}]{}{21}{21}\\
  %CONFERENCES
  \ganttbar[inline=false,bar/.style={draw=none, fill=none},bar label font = \normalfont]{Conferences}{1}{1}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=red}]{}{6}{6}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=red}]{}{12}{12}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=red}]{}{18}{18}
  \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=red}]{}{24}{24}
\end{ganttchart}
```

It used to work perfectly well when I wrote it two years ago, but now (probably after some system updates - I am using Debian stable) it is rendered completely wrongly:

[image: wrong gantt chart]

I am expecting to gett all the elements under the appropriate month number. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you made a typographical error, but all I changed was `]{24}{24}` to `]{1}{24}` in line 13 of the code you posted. I think this produces the Gantt chart you wanted.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,crop=true]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \begin{ganttchart}[
        inline, 
        hgrid style/.style={draw=black!5, line width=.75pt},
        vgrid={*1{draw=black!5, line width=.75pt}},
        title top shift = .4,
        group label font = \tiny,
        group left shift = .1,
        group right shift = -.1,
        bar label font = \tiny,
        milestone label font = \tiny,
        bar label inline anchor/.style={above=0.1cm},
        milestone label inline anchor/.style={above=0.1cm}
      ]{1}{24}
      \gantttitle{Month}{24}\\
      \gantttitlelist{1,...,24}{1}\\
      \ganttbar[inline=false,bar/.style={draw=none, fill=none},bar label font = \normalfont]{Work packages}{1}{1}
      \ganttgroup{Familiarising}{1}{6}
      \ganttgroup{Core}{6}{12}
      \ganttgroup{Application}{13}{24}\\
      %DELIVERABLES
      \ganttbar[inline=false,bar/.style={draw=none, fill=none},bar label font = \normalfont]{Deliverables}{1}{1}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=blue}]{1.1}{3}{3}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=blue}]{1.2}{6}{6}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=blue}]{2.1,2.2,2.3}{12}{12}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=blue}]{3.2,3.4}{18}{18}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=blue}]{3.1,3.3}{24}{24}\\
      %MILESTONES
      \ganttbar[inline=false,bar/.style={draw=none, fill=none},bar label font = \normalfont]{Milestones}{1}{1}
      \ganttmilestone{6m}{6}
      \ganttmilestone{12m}{12}
      \ganttmilestone{18m}{18}
      \ganttmilestone{24m}{24}\\
      %SEMINARS
      \ganttbar[inline=false,bar/.style={draw=none, fill=none},bar label font = \normalfont]{Seminars}{1}{1}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=orange}]{}{3}{3}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=orange}]{}{9}{9}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=orange}]{}{15}{15}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=orange}]{}{21}{21}\\
      %CONFERENCES
      \ganttbar[inline=false,bar/.style={draw=none, fill=none},bar label font = \normalfont]{Conferences}{1}{1}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=red}]{}{6}{6}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=red}]{}{12}{12}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=red}]{}{18}{18}
      \ganttbar[bar/.style={draw=none, fill=red}]{}{24}{24}
    \end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

[image]